# Arrange six cigarettes in such a way that each cigarette touches every other cigarette

Tags: geometry, combinatorics

What are some ways to arrange six cigarettes in such a way that each cigarette touches every other cigarette?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my solution: $\phantom{body too short}$

> [image]